# singleton part and element part in abstract algebra

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If I say

Let P denote the partition of

{0,1,...,99} into 100 singleton parts

and Q denote the partition of {0,1,...,99} into one 100-element part,

Is it correct if I write it as below?

P = { [1],[2],[3],...,[99] }

Q = { [1,2,3,...,99] }

I thought singleton was a set with single element but I am not sure if this is correct or not.

If anyone could help it would be great

Comment: I disagree with the use of square brackets, but otherwise yes this is correct except for a few minor typos.  Singleton sets are sets with precisely one element.  Parts are themselves sets as well, and sets are written with curly brackets.  Further, you forgot zero when you wrote $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: Square brackets are occasionally used to denote equivalence classes, but they generally only are written with a single "representative element" within them rather than every element.  For example, in $\Bbb Z_2$ the partition of $\Bbb Z$ into even and odd parts one would write $\Bbb Z_2 = \{\{\dots,-4,-2,0,2,4,\dots\},\{\dots,-3,-1,1,3,5,\dots\}\}=\{[0],[1]\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The usual set-theoretic notation in math would be:

$$P = \{ \{0\},\{1\},\dots,\{99\}\}$$

$$Q = \{\{0,1,\dots,99\}\}$$

(You left out the $0$s.)